# No network out of the box?

Tags: networking

New Rpi 3B+, fresh download of Raspian image, Boots OK, Goes through the setup (localization, time zone, etc), and even finds my WiFi AP and asks for my password.

But, WiFi says "Wlan0 not associated"
And ifconfig shows a rather strange IP address for eth0, and only an IPV6 address for wlan0.

As stated above- this is right out of the box with a fresh burn of Raspian.  I didn't add anything to the /root of the SD card (ssh or wpa_supplicant.conf files).

So, any guesses why I am not getting a network connection?

Note, this is not my first Pi and getting the network to connect is a major headache every time.  I normally just clone a working SD card, but I wanted to start this Pi with a fresh Raspian download.

Comment: Half-fixed.  I removed the quotes from the wep_key0= line in my wpa_supplicant.conf file, and now wlan0 is working.  But, still no ethernet.  eth0 is up, but ifconfig still shows a strange IP address out of my network.

Comment: what is the content of wpa_supplicant.conf - do you have a country code set for example? .. `a rather strange IP address for eth0` if you have nothing connected to eth0, I'd be surprised if it had any IP address at all

Comment: If you are actually using `WEP` (which is insecure) the automatic procedure will not work. You may find some answers for setting up `WEP` e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/69639/8697

Comment: Remember, this is "right out of the box" with a fresh download of the Raspian with Desktop image.  On first boot, I am prompted with localization questions, a password change screen, then a prompt to select my AP and enter the password.  The Raspian setup generated a wpa_supplicant.conf file.  Here is the whole wpa_supplicant file:
 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="Kaywinnet"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        wep_key0=806194edb8
}