# Raspberry Pi 3 Not Connecting to Network

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, raspbian-lite

I have changed the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file on my Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian Lite) to the proper SSID and password of our WPA2 WiFi, and it shows the proper SSID when running `iwconfig`. However:

- When I run `nmcli general status`, it says the Raspberry Pi is disconnected.
- The Raspberry Pi is not detected on our router's configuration page.
- The `/etc/network/interfaces` file only contains comments and a reference to an empty source directory (`interfaces.d`), unlike how I've typically seen the file online.

The `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file currently looks like this (with the SSID and password replaced by the proper information):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="wifi_name"
    psk="wifi_password"
}
```

How could I establish a functioning connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting the Pi3 automatically to Wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/connecting-the-pi3-automatically-to-wifi)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Not only is the question not duplicate, the answers to suggested duplicate are WRONG or unhelpful.

Comment: @Milliways Is this question not about connecting the RPi3 to a given WiFi automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you running?

`nmcli` is a command-line tool for controlling `NetworkManager` which is **NOT installed** or used by Raspbian. `NetworkManager` does not use `wpa_supplicant.conf`

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for setting up networking on Raspbian.

Comment: I'm running Raspbian Lite and have installed network manager, but from what you're saying, it sounds as if `nmcli` may produce unreliable results. My Raspberry Pi was successful when I `ping`ed to various sites and my local gateway, so why do you think it's not shown as an "attached device" to my router? I have already followed the steps in your link.

Comment: You have 2 incompatible network managers installed `NetworkManager` and `dhcpcd` (the standard).  The link describes configuring `dhcpcd` on Raspbian; if you want to use `NetworkManager` you will have to configure it, but this is normally done by the GUI. Don't expect any help for `NetworkManager` on this site - try a Ubuntu forum.

Comment: I ended up switching the OS from Raspbian Lite to the full version of Raspbian, and that did the trick. Thanks for taking the time to help!